# Reset Timestamp in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, calendar, timestamp, reset

What is the best way to write the following code snippet in Java 8?

```
private Timestamp resetTime(Timestamp ts) {
    ts.setHours(0);
    ts.setMinutes(0);
    ts.setSeconds(0);   
    return ts;
}
```

I was going to use the Calendar class but then read that it is advisable not to do so in Java 8. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to try to adjust the `Timestamp` object to the start of the day in the default time zone (it doesn’t in all cases do that to perfection).

In the old days we used `Timestamp` to transfer a value to an SQL timestamp with or without time zone. The latter is somewhat self-contradictory: a time stamp is supposed to define a point in time, but a date and time of day without time zone or UTC offset doesn’t do that. So let’s first assume that you want a value to transfer to an SQL database that needs a `timestamp with time zone`. The type to use for that in Java 8 (assuming JDBC 4.2 or later driver) is `OffsetDateTime` (some JDBC drivers also accept `Instant`). Since the databases I know of always use UTC as time zone, I find it most natural and least confusing to transfer an `OffsetDateTime` in UTC.

```
private OffsetDateTime resetTime(LocalDate date) {
    return date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toOffsetDateTime()
            .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
}
```

Example use:

```
    OffsetDateTime ts = resetTime(LocalDate.of(2019, Month.NOVEMBER, 30));
    System.out.println(ts);
```

Output when running in the Africa/Blantyre time zone (just to pick a time zone at random):

> 2019-11-29T22:00Z

My method accepts a `LocalDate` argument. A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day and all that the method needs since it is setting the time of day to 00:00:00 anyway.

Should your database require a `timestamp` without time zone (not recommended), you will need a `LocalDateTime` instead:

```
private LocalDateTime resetTime(LocalDate date) {
    return date.atStartOfDay();
}
```

> I was going to use the Calendar class but then read that it is
>   advisable not to do so in Java 8.

Your are completely correct. Before the advent of java.time in 2014 the `Timestamp` class was used with SQL databases and the `Calendar` class would have been the correct means for you task (with the Joda-Time library as a probably better alternative). Even though both `Timestamp` and `Calendar` were poorly designed. Now they are long outdated, we should not use any of them anymore.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

You can user java.time.ZonedDateTime and java.sql.Timestamp together

Timestamp.valueOf(ZonedDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).toLocalDateTime());

Comment: Assuming that the questioner cannot avoid the need for a `Timestamp` and that s/he wants to throw away the time zone information, this is an elegant solution using java.time.